# apostrophe not preceded by \ - values-fr.xml file not saved after changes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-resources

I'm working on building an app based on some open source code I found on GitHub. Just trying to launch the app in AndroidStudio for the first time.

I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':ui:processDebugResources'.
```

It is preceded by errors from the values-fr.xml file such as:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Apostrophe not preceded by \\ (in points d\u0027accentuation en bas)","sources":[{"file":"/Users/Chloe/Downloads/Readily-master/ui/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-fr/values-fr.xml","position":{"startLine":20}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Apostrophe not preceded by \\ (in Application d\u0027e-mail introuvable)","sources":[{"file":"/Users/Chloe/Downloads/Readily-master/ui/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-fr/values-fr.xml","position":{"startLine":59}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

I understand that apostrophes in strings need to be preceded with a . My problem is that after I go through and add the \'s and go to "Make Project", I'm met with the same errors and find that the XML file has reverted to its original state.

Any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

EDITING: to add the values-fr.xml file as requested...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string msgid="4600421777120114993" name="abc_action_bar_home_description">"Revenir à l\'accueil"</string>
    <string msgid="1397052879051804371" name="abc_action_bar_home_description_format">"%1$s, %2$s"</string>
    <string msgid="6623331958280229229" name="abc_action_bar_home_subtitle_description_format">"%1$s, %2$s, %3$s"</string>
    <string msgid="1594238315039666878" name="abc_action_bar_up_description">"Revenir en haut de la page"</string>
    <string msgid="3588849162933574182" name="abc_action_menu_overflow_description">"Plus d\'options"</string>
    <string msgid="4076576682505996667" name="abc_action_mode_done">"OK"</string>
    <string msgid="7468859129482906941" name="abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all">"Tout afficher"</string>
    <string msgid="2031811694353399454" name="abc_activitychooserview_choose_application">"Sélectionner une application"</string>
    <string msgid="3691816814315814921" name="abc_searchview_description_clear">"Effacer la requête"</string>
    <string msgid="2550479030709304392" name="abc_searchview_description_query">"Requête de recherche"</string>
    <string msgid="8264924765203268293" name="abc_searchview_description_search">"Rechercher"</string>
    <string msgid="8928215447528550784" name="abc_searchview_description_submit">"Envoyer la requête"</string>
    <string msgid="893419373245838918" name="abc_searchview_description_voice">"Recherche vocale"</string>
    <string msgid="3421042268587513524" name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with">"Partager avec"</string>
    <string msgid="7165123711973476752" name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with_application">"Partager avec %s"</string>
    <string name="about">Information Générale</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Paramètres</string>
    <string name="app_name">Readily</string>
    <string name="bottom_pointer_description">points d'accentuation en bas</string>
    <string name="cant_fetch">Problème lors de la recuperation du texte</string>
    <string name="choose_file">Choisissez un fichier</string>
    <string name="clipboard_button">Lire un texte depuis le presse papier</string>
    <string name="clipboard_empty">Le presse papier est vide</string>
    <string msgid="473679118463211576" name="common_android_wear_notification_needs_update_text">"Une application nécessite une mise à jour du Bios de l\'application Android Wear."</string>
    <string msgid="3046420540094071256" name="common_android_wear_update_text">"Cette application ne fonctionnera pas tant que vous n\'aurez pas mis à jour l\'application Android Wear."</string>
    <string msgid="1366439133145190222" name="common_android_wear_update_title">"Mettre à jour Android Wear"</string>
    <string msgid="4181637455539816337" name="common_google_play_services_enable_button">"Activer services Google Play"</string>
    <string msgid="7627896071867667758" name="common_google_play_services_enable_text">"Cette application ne fonctionnera pas tant que vous n\'aurez pas activé les services Google Play."</string>
    <string msgid="529078775174559253" name="common_google_play_services_enable_title">"Activer les services Google Play"</string>
    <string msgid="2443362625939284971" name="common_google_play_services_error_notification_requested_by_msg">"Notification issue de l\'application \"<ns1:g id="APP_NAME">%1$s</ns1:g>\""</string>
    <string msgid="8515591849428043265" name="common_google_play_services_install_button">"Installer services Google Play"</string>
    <string msgid="8685301130651051380" name="common_google_play_services_install_text_phone">"Cette application ne fonctionnera pas sans les services Google Play, qui ne sont pas installés sur votre téléphone."</string>
    <string msgid="1589957570365247855" name="common_google_play_services_install_text_tablet">"Cette application ne fonctionnera pas sans les services Google Play, qui ne sont pas installés sur votre tablette."</string>
    <string msgid="26645092511305524" name="common_google_play_services_install_title">"Installer les services Google Play"</string>
    <string msgid="4983316348021735578" name="common_google_play_services_invalid_account_text">"Le compte indiqué n\'existe pas sur cet appareil. Veuillez sélectionner un autre compte."</string>
    <string msgid="1066672360770936753" name="common_google_play_services_invalid_account_title">"Compte erroné"</string>
    <string msgid="2583358409598976717" name="common_google_play_services_needs_enabling_title">"Une application demande l\'activation des services Google Play."</string>
    <string msgid="9038847255613537209" name="common_google_play_services_network_error_text">"Vous devez disposer d\'une connexion de données pour utiliser les services Google Play."</string>
    <string msgid="3827284619958211114" name="common_google_play_services_network_error_title">"Erreur réseau"</string>
    <string msgid="8120534356798772974" name="common_google_play_services_notification_needs_installation_title">"Une application demande l\'installation des services Google Play."</string>
    <string msgid="1388129345631079938" name="common_google_play_services_notification_needs_update_title">"Une application demande la mise à jour des services Google Play."</string>
    <string msgid="1852570676146674985" name="common_google_play_services_notification_ticker">"Erreur liée aux services Google Play"</string>
    <string msgid="4762332809710093730" name="common_google_play_services_unknown_issue">"Problème inconnu avec les services Google Play."</string>
    <string msgid="3542578567569488671" name="common_google_play_services_unsupported_text">"Les services Google Play, dont dépendent certaines de vos applications, ne sont pas compatibles avec votre appareil. Veuillez contacter le fabricant pour obtenir de l\'aide."</string>
    <string msgid="6334768798839376943" name="common_google_play_services_unsupported_title">"Services Google Play"</string>
    <string msgid="8932944190611227642" name="common_google_play_services_update_button">"Mettre à jour"</string>
    <string msgid="448354684997260580" name="common_google_play_services_update_text">"Cette application ne fonctionnera pas tant que vous n\'aurez pas mis à jour les services Google Play."</string>
    <string msgid="6006316683626838685" name="common_google_play_services_update_title">"Mettre à jour les services Google Play"</string>
    <string msgid="411506735369601515" name="common_open_on_phone">"Ouvrir sur le téléphone"</string>
    <string msgid="9071884888741449141" name="common_signin_button_text">"Connexion"</string>
    <string msgid="2429381841831957106" name="common_signin_button_text_long">"Se connecter avec Google"</string>
    <string name="confirmation_dialog_title">Êtes vous sure?</string>
    <string name="continue_reading">Continuer</string>
    <string name="delete">Supprimer</string>
    <string name="editor_dialog_header_hint">Titre de la lecture (e.g. "The Shining")</string>
    <string name="editor_dialog_position_hint">Position dans le texte</string>
    <string name="editor_dialog_title">Modifier la lecture</string>
    <string name="email_app_not_found">Application d'e-mail introuvable</string>
    <string name="empty_directory">Dossier vide</string>
    <string name="enjoyit">Profitez bien ;)</string>
    <string name="error_selecting_file">Erreur lors de la sélection du fichier</string>
    <string name="file_manager_required">Installez un gestionnaire de fichier s'il vous plait</string>
    <string name="finish">Fin</string>
    <string name="gonna_delete">Vous êtes en train de supprimer cet élément. Cette action ne peut être annulée!</string>
    <string name="hint_font_size">Entrez une taille et regarder l'exemple ci-dessus</string>
    <string name="illegal_value">Valeur interdite</string>
    <string name="instructions_controls_header">Controles</string>
    <string name="instructions_emphasis_point"> Points d'emphases : en vous concentrant dessus la lecture devient plus rapide.</string>
    <string name="instructions_fifth_paragraph">Pour mettre le lecteur en pause ou le relancer il suffit de toucher sa fenetre.
    Selon vos préferences vous pourrez faire glisser le contenu
    ou utiliser un bouton pour acceder au mot précédent du texte.\n
    Si vous sentez que la lecture est trop lente ou trop rapide vous pouvez changer la vitesse en cours de lecture :
            Glisser vers le haut ou vers le bas to modifier la vitesse de 50MPM (Mots par Minutes).</string>
    <string name="instructions_first_paragraph">"Readily est une application de lecture rapide pour android
    propulsée par la technologie RSVP (Rapid Serial Visual Presentation). 
    Elle vous permet de lire jusqu'à 1 200 mots par minute au lieu de 220 lors d'une lecture normale."</string>
    <string name="instructions_fourth_paragraph">Enfin, vous pouvez partager des données avec Readily
    depuis votre lecteur favoris (e.g. Flipboard, Instapaper).</string>
    <string name="instructions_notification">"Notification : elles n'apparaitront qu'en cas de modifications
        (e.g. lorsque vous changez la vitesse de lecture)."</string>
    <string name="instructions_previous_word_button">Boutton pour le mot précedent (optionel) : 
        une alternative au défilement par glissement droite gauche. Il apparaitra lors de la pause.</string>
    <string name="instructions_progress_bar">Bar de progression : elle indique votre progression dans le texte.</string>
    <string name="instructions_second_paragraph">"Pour commencer à lire vous pouvez copier un texte dans le presse papier
    et choisir l'action \'Lire un texte depuis le presse papier\'."</string>
    <string name="instructions_source_text">Sources de texte</string>
    <string name="instructions_third_paragraph">"Vous pouvez aussi utiliser l'action \"Lire un texte depuis un fichier\"
    et choisir un fichier (ayant pour extension .txt, .epub ou .fb2) depuis le gestionnaire de fichier du systàme."</string>
    <string name="instructions_welcome">Bienvennue!</string>
    <string name="just_sample">Example</string>
    <string name="list_empty_view">Hey, lisez quelque chose!</string>
    <string name="mail_to_me">mailto:syniuhin@gmail.com</string>
    <string name="next">Suivant</string>
    <string name="next_words">mots suivants</string>
    <string name="path">Chemin vers un ficher</string>
    <string name="pause">Pause</string>
    <string name="percent_left">Restant: </string>
    <string name="position">Position dans le texte</string>
    <string name="preference_cache">Sauvegarder les lectures</string>
    <string name="preference_cache_summary">Mettre en cache les lectures non terminées</string>
    <string name="preference_dark_theme">Theme sombre</string>
    <string name="preference_font_size">Taille de la police</string>
    <string name="preference_font_size_summary">Attention : le texte risque de dépasser de la fenêtre</string>
    <string name="preferences_advanced">Paramètres avancés</string>
    <string name="preferences_again">Conserver les lectures terminées</string>
    <string name="preferences_again_summary">Do not delete readings when you complete them</string>
    <string name="preferences_basic_settings">Paramètres de base</string>
    <string name="preferences_begOfPar_coeff">Début d'un paragraphe</string>
    <string name="preferences_clipboard">Lire un texte depuis le presse papier</string>
    <string name="preferences_comaOrLong_coeff">Virgule/mot long</string>
    <string name="preferences_dashOrColon_coeff">Tiret ou point(virgule)</string>
    <string name="preferences_different_speed_punctuation">Changer la vitesse pour la ponctuation</string>
    <string name="preferences_different_speed_punctuation_summary">e.g. à la rencontre d'un point ou d'une virgule</string>
    <string name="preferences_endOfSentence_coeff">Fin de phrase</string>
    <string name="preferences_instrucions">Instructions</string>
    <string name="preferences_pick_file">Lire un texte depuis un fichier</string>
    <string name="preferences_pick_file_summary">Choisissez un fichier .txt, .epub or .fb2 à lire</string>
    <string name="preferences_punctuation_settings">Vitesse et ponctuation</string>
    <string name="preferences_send_feedback">Donner votre avis</string>
    <string name="preferences_send_feedback_summary">Faites moi part de vos idées :)</string>
    <string name="preferences_set_wpm">Vitesse de lecture</string>
    <string name="preferences_set_wpm_summary">Nombre de mots par minute</string>
    <string name="preferences_share_feedback">Avis</string>
    <string name="preferences_showContext">Afficher le contexte</string>
    <string name="preferences_showContext_summary">Mot suivant dans la phrase</string>
    <string name="preferences_swipe">Glisser pour faire défiler</string>
    <string name="preferences_swipe_summary">Left to next word, right to previous one</string>
    <string name="preferences_test">Tester vos paramètres</string>
    <string name="reading_is_completed">Toucher pour quitter</string>
    <string name="sample_text">Au-dehors, même à travers le carreau de la fenêtre fermée, le monde paraissait froid.
        Dans la rue, de petits remous de vent faisaient tourner en spirale la poussière et le papier déchiré.
        Bien que le soleil brillât et que le ciel fût d’un bleu dur, tout semblait décoloré,
        hormis les affiches collées partout. De tous les carrefours importants,
        le visage à la moustache noire vous fixait du regard.
        Il y en avait un sur le mur d’en face. BIG BROTHER VOUS REGARDE, répétait la légende,
        tandis que le regard des yeux noirs pénétrait les yeux de Winston. Au niveau de la rue, une autre affiche,
        dont un angle était déchiré, battait par à-coups dans le vent, couvrant et découvrant alternativement un seul mot :
        ANGSOC. Au loin, un hélicoptère glissa entre les toits, plana un moment, telle une mouche bleue,
        puis repartit comme une flèche, dans un vol courbe.</string>
    <string name="send_email">Envoyez un email</string>
    <string name="speed">Vitesse: </string>
    <string name="sth_left">restant</string>
    <string name="storage_removed">Le stockage a été enlevé ou démonté.</string>
    <string name="tap_to_start">Touchez pour démarrer</string>
    <string name="text_null">Texte introuvable</string>
    <string name="title">Titre</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">Readily</string>
    <string name="title_activity_receiver">Ajouter à Readily</string>
    <string name="title_activity_settings">Paramètres</string>
    <string name="top_pointer_description">points d'accentuation en haut</string>
    <string name="wrong_ext">Extension incorrecte</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: The error is in the values-fr.xml. Please [edit] your question and add it here

Comment: Okay, done. The problem is with the apostrophe's in the french strings not being preceded by \, and when I add them, the changes are not saved.

Comment: If you edit them in the `res` folder of the project, the changes should be saved.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! If you add that as an answer, I will mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making changes in the `build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-fr/values-fr.xml` file won't work because that file is auto generated.

To make changes that can be saved, edit the files under the `res` folder of the app

Comment: It works! I was driving me crazy the values-fr.xml file. Thanks.